# How to share movies inside the home network without password?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-vista, network-shares, file-sharing

This is the situation:

We have a broadband connection which is shared by 6 people who have different os'es and laptops.

But now we are planning to share movies among 6 people... How to achieve this? I dont have any idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One computer will have to act as a network share. A physical location of your movie files. That computer then has to share that folder/directory with the other computers. Depending on the OS of the computer that has the movie files on it, check below for tutorials.

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Sharing_Ubuntu_Linux_Folders_with_Remote_Windows_Systems

Answer (score 1):

A bit of an expensive solution, but one which requires minimal setup/administration is a NAS client like the NETGEAR ReadyNAS NV+ (you can find it on Amazon amongst other places). It has 4 slots for SATA hard drives and you can buy just the NAS unit or get it along with 2 or 4 pre-installed 500GB or 1TB disks. This eliminates the need to run a dedicated server just to share movies amongst a couple of people.

Alternately, you could just set up Windows filesharing on the Windows systems and run Samba on the linux/unix systems. This means that you have access to each other's movies/music/whatever, but only when their computer is on.

Answer (score -1):

You could run some p2p sharing within your network. [DC++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC%2B%2B) might be a good choice. You need to make one of the computers a server/hub.

Comment: If you're downvoting, please be kind enough to mention the reason.

Comment: I think it's a complicated and useless solution for such a simple program. This requires the movie files to be on every computer seperately. The pro about a share/NAS is that you only need one central storage.

Comment: Depends on the amount of hardware/software you want to throw at it, and for how long. Even FTP can do the job for some people.

Comment: I'd even recommend FTP over P2P sharing for this one...

Comment: Ennappa Abhinave, Naimkaa.. Thuimba Kova patrini... ( sorry for my kannada)